# Programmatically get the driver name of a Laravel storage disk at runtime

Tags: laravel, laravel-storage

I have a particular "disk" object obtained from the Laravel Storage facade, i.e. `$disk = Storage::disk('some-name')`. How do I get the name of the driver for that disk `$disk`?

In particular I need to find out, if symbolic links are supported or not. This is true for the "local" driver but not for the "s3" driver. At the moment I am thinking of something like that:

```
function myFunction(\Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem $disk) {
  /** @var string $driverName */
  $driverName = // somehow get the name of the driver which is used by $disk
  if ($driverName === 'local' ) {
    // Yeah, we support symbolic links
    // do something
  } else {
    // We cannot use symbolic links
    // inform the user and log an warning to the logs
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, in a local test, `Storage::disk('local')` returns an instance of `FilesystemAdapter`, which has a `getDriver()` method, but that returns an instance of `League\Flysystem\Filesystem`, which I'm not sure of available methods. For reference: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.html

Comment: For the `Illuminate\Contratcs\Filesystem\Filesystem`, these are the available methods: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Filesystem/Filesystem.html, but I'm not sure `$disk` would be an instance of that Class.

Comment: I think `League\Flysystem\Filesystem::$adapter` is what you're after, but it's protected. It would be an instance of, e.g. `League\Flysystem\AwsS3V3\AwsS3V3Adapter` or `League\Flysystem\Local\LocalAdapter`.

Comment: In Laravel 10:
League\Flysystem\Local\LocalFilesystemAdapter  => local driver

Answer (score -1):

I also faced a similar task, but I needed to determine the FTP adapter.
Everything turned out to be very simple.
At least Filesystem 1.0 has a [getAdapter()](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/094defdb4a7001845300334e7c1ee2335925ef99/src/Filesystem.php#L46) method that gets an adapter object.

### First way

```
$diskName = "disk_name";
if (strtolower(config("filesystems.disks.{$diskName}.driver") == 'ftp') {
    // Remote
} else {
    // Local
}
```

### Second way

```
$diskName = "disk_name";
$disk = Storage::disk($diskName);
if ($disk->getAdapter() instanceof \League\Flysystem\Adapter\Ftp) {
    // Remote
} else {
    // Local
}
```